Crystal Report Loop Formula
Good day,
I don't know if this is the correct forum, I am building a Crystal report that is linked to a Boyum Button in SAP.
Now I am trying to do a formula in Crystal but it is currently only looking at first row. I tried to do a loop, but its keep on saying there is something wrong. Please can you advise how I can fix this or create a loop. Here is my formula.
It needs to loop through all rows in Line sequence
NumberVar i;
StringVar foundLocation := "-";

// Loop through each row of the SP_CARLA_TruckPlanningReport dataset
for i := 1 to Count({SP_CARLA_TruckPlanningReport;1.u_prodloc}),
    // Check if the current row's line sequence matches 2
    if {@linesequence}[i] = 2 then 
        // Set foundLocation to the corresponding location
        foundLocation := {SP_CARLA_TruckPlanningReport;1.u_prodloc}[i]
        // Exit the loop if a match is found
    Exit For;
    else 0;
Next i;

enter image description here
Tried to do a loop - formula above

This formula won't allow you to loop through the rows of the dataset.  Crystal Reports prints reports by section.  If you want to evaluate values in each datarow, you can do that with fields and formulas placed within the Details section of the report.  You may also have Group Header and Group Footer sections if your report uses grouping levels.  The LOOP structure you tried is intended to loop through a list or array of values within the current section.  There are functions to read the previous and next datarows, but the rest of the data set is effectively out of scope.
